# Does history.goBack() keeps last pushed state?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

Does `history.goBack()` to the previous page, from "SignIn" component is passing the last `state` that was pushed to it
from another component -

```
     history.push({
    pathname: '/signin',
    state: { from: true },
});
```

Is the `state` stays in the history?

Answer (score 2):

No it will also get back to the prevoius pushed state.

You can examine location.state simply by using useLocation hook.

https://codesandbox.io/s/uselocation-rhz1d

Comment: Than why "No" if it will go to the previous pushed state. Thanks